# Minimizing attribute tables in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, windows-7, citrix

Prior to ArcGIS 10.0, I worked on several attribute tables at once and I often minimized them.

Now, the attribute tables have no icon to minimize them using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop on our Windows 7 computer.

We have them on PC and in Citrix as well, and the software behaviour is the same there.

Is there a way to get attribute tables to minimize?

Comment: I don't know why, it's got a pin to 'auto hide' if it's docked. I wasn't happy about the changes to the attribute table - now you can't have two open at the same time and see both as the 2nd and subsequent turn into tabs. Do you have any development skills? You can create a grid view form that you can minimize and even put on your most commonly used buttons - but you'd need to code that yourself.

Comment: Michael, Actually you can have two AT open at the same time. Simply drag one tab to see two tables side by side

Comment: @FaridCher In which version are you seeing that?  At 10.3.1 I am not able to unstack the Table windows, and I do not recall any version since 10.0 (where this suboptimal behaviour was introduced) that could.  On the other hand ArcGIS Pro behaves precisely the way that you describe.

Comment: @Polygeo I use version 10.2.2 with all patches installed. But I think that is working with other versions (above 10) too. I can share snapshots if you want

Comment: @FaridCher I would be very keen to see snapshots posted here because I think this has been unsatisfactory behaviour from ArcMap since 10.0: http://polygeo.com.au/2013/06/04/top-10-improvements-id-like-to-see-in-arcgis-10-2-for-desktop-6-attribute-table-windows-improvements/  I'm assuming that you have the dockable vs stackable terminology correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no minimize button and I think it is not necessary. At 10, dockable panels were introduced. Once you dock the dockable window, there is an autohide button (which emulates minimize button) to let you hide or show the dockable windows on demand.

**Update**

To address Micheal's comment:

[image]

Comment: But what if you don't want it docked. What if you want to see two (or more) attribute tables at the same time. I have more than one monitor and like to get ArcGis as big as possible and use my other monitors for the Info, Table of Contents, overview (if needed), attribute tables and any more that I need. I don't want to dock *any* of these windows. The search, results etc.. I use less frequently and am happy to dock these with auto-hide. I wouldn't be the only one who feels this behavior is sub optimal.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I haven't worked with two monitors but with attribute table you can see two or more attribute tables at the same time

Comment: Thanks for that Farid, I didn't know you could do that until you mentioned it (+1 for that). I was able to do as such with ArcGis 10.2 using your instructions. It still doesn't get a 'tab' in the taskbar so you can't alt-TAB to each one but still that's a lot more usable for me. Try get another monitor, almost all video cards made in the last 5 years support dual monitor and almost all notebooks have either analog or digital 2nd monitor. The immediate performance increase gained by being able to utilize a single monitor for the ArcMap main window will surprise you.

Comment: and as another hint, you can actually navigate between tabs using ***CTRL+TAB***, instead of ALT+TAB

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion (dual monitor). I will give it a try ;)

Comment: What your screenshot shows is Tab Groups.  The only way I knew to create those was via Table Options | Arrange Tables, but tearing them off by their tabs and placing them on the blue targets is a better method - so thanks for that!  However, I do think that having them always contained within one table window remains quite restrictive compared to ArcMap pre-10.0 and ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: @PolyGeo Is it really necessary to have them outside of one container (attribute table)? I can't think of a reason!

Comment: It's a usability issue.  Imagine that I am a typical user nowadays with dual monitors.  I may want a very wide table displayed on my left hand screen (which I can minimize to get at my email behind), and a tiny table or two open at the same time closer to the map data on my right hand screen.  It's not enough to make me stop using ArcMap but it is enough to have me wish for Attribute Tables a la 9.3 or Pro.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson "The immediate performance increase gained by being able to utilize a single monitor for the ArcMap main window will surprise you" - until you remove the second monitor and try to re-open the attribute table ;)

Comment: Yes @StephenLead ;) been there too, it will come up mostly outside the window (like when you open someone elses' document who has a bigger monitor). I experience that when I remote desktop in from home. If you have any trouble with windows appearing off screen change your screen resolution (800 x 600 works) then change it back to what it was and all your windows will be visible (but messy). Once you get used to working with multiple monitors you will find it very hard to go back to one so fight tooth-and-nail *not* to get it taken away.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Table" in the top left on the Attribute Table screen that pops up when you right click an attribute on the table of contents on the map screen.  Tabs for multiple tables show up on your map screen.  Close the attribute table window to see your map which will have tables on the far left.  Only other possibility is that I clicked the attribute name i.e. water on this screen shot.  I had been following advice to double click the name, and then clicked Table, which is what I think fixed it.  I now can't recreate the frozen-open maximized Table Attribute screen (in 10.2.2 Arc in Windows 10).  Something is fixed, not positive how. [image: Screen shot of clicked Table location]  Once done, can use Arrange Tables new Vertical Tab Group to allow many side by side table windows which can be stretched or shrunk clicking vertical frame edge.

[image: view multiple tables]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot to illustrate this? I'm unsure what you mean by "the Attribute Table screen" and where to "click Table"

Comment: How do I add the shot?  It wouldn't copy/paste in

Comment: Click the _edit_ button above, then use the image button (the 6th button from the left) to upload a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using ArcMap, you may want to look at ArcGIS Pro.

As you can see in the graphic below I have two attribute panes floating separately (ready to be moved to another screen, if I wish), and two others docked with tabs at the bottom.

[image]

Technically there still seems to be no option to minimize these panes, or to auto-hide (unpin) them like you can other panes, but I think being able to have them float freely again is a big improvement from ArcMap 10.x.

Answer (score 0):

First grab the bar that says table (the one at the top) and drag it down a few inches (left click, hold, and and drag).

Next, put the cursor over the top border of the table, so the cursor turns to a double arrow. Click and drag down the top boundary of the table 6 inches or so.

Then grab the bar that says table again and move the whole table upwards. You should find that the bottom edge of the table is now accessible.

Put your cursor at the bottom right corner, let it turn to a double arrow, and resize to your liking.